# How does Python's `file.read` function figure out the size of the file?

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, cpython

I am looking at the source code for `Python-2.7.6` to figure this out.

In `Objects/fileobject.c`, line 1052, there is a function called `file_read`, which I am guessing corresponds to the function `read` on the file object in `Python`.

On line 1067 of the same file, I see the following line. Note that `bytesrequested` is used further down in the function to decide the size of the buffer to allocate for storing the file.

```
 if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|l:read", &bytesrequested))
```

It looks like the number of bytes requested is somehow encoded inside `args`, which has type `PyObject*`.  Thus, the natural place to continue the search is to find out where `file_read` is called.

However, I cannot find any place in the entire Python source tree (recursive grep) where `file_read` is actually called, so I cannot continue the trace to find out how `bytesrequested` is actually computed. 
Is `file_read` somehow called under a different name in a different part of the source tree?

Comment: Isn't ``bytesrequests`` coming from userland Python? See: ``help(file.read)``

Comment: Oops, I totally forgot to check that. I have always assumed that `file.read` doesn't take parameters, since I have never seen it called with parameters.

Comment: It most certainly does. An optional argument. I suspect you'll find more C source code that checks to see if a ``Null/None`` argument was passed as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [line 2114](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c10ea224392d/Objects/fileobject.c#l2114)

`file_read` is python's `file.read` method.  The `args` in the C code are the arguments that you pass to `file.read`.  `bytesrequested` is whatever you pass as the argument to `file.read`

```
with open('file') as fin:
    fin.read(5)  # bytesrequested will be 5.
```